# socket is closed - c# server android client

Tags: c#, android, sockets, client

I have following codes. My c# server and Android client can seamlessly connect when click connect button but after connect I can not send data form android client to c# server, Android client says: "socket is closed"

When I click connect button android is connect and server accept but I click send client says socket is closed

### c# server

```
    public class SoketPaketi
    {
        public Socket soket;
        public int istemciNo;
        public byte[] tampon = new byte[1024];

        public SoketPaketi(Socket soc, int no)
        {
            this.soket = soc;
            this.istemciNo = no;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dinlemeyeBasla();
    }

    private void dinlemeyeBasla()
    {
        sunucuSoketi = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint IP_PORT = new IPEndPoint(IP_ADRES,PORT);
        sunucuSoketi.Bind(IP_PORT);
        sunucuSoketi.Listen(10);
        Console.WriteLine("Server Dinlemeye Başladı.. " + IP_PORT.ToString());
        sunucuSoketi.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(onBaglanmaIstegiGeldiginde), null);
    }

    private void onBaglanmaIstegiGeldiginde(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket calismaSoketi = sunucuSoketi.EndAccept(ar);
        istemciler.Add(calismaSoketi);
        veriBekle(calismaSoketi,istemciler.Count - 1);
        sunucuSoketi.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(onBaglanmaIstegiGeldiginde), null);
        Console.WriteLine("İstemci Bağlantısı Kabul Edildi..");
    }

    private void veriBekle(Socket socket, int istemciNo)
    {
        try
        {
            if (geriBildirim == null)
            {
                geriBildirim = new AsyncCallback(onVeriGeldiginde);
            }
            SoketPaketi soketPaketi = new SoketPaketi(socket, istemciNo);
            socket.BeginReceive(soketPaketi.tampon, 0, soketPaketi.tampon.Length,SocketFlags.None, onVeriGeldiginde, soketPaketi);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }

    private void onVeriGeldiginde(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("onVeriGeldiginde");
        SoketPaketi soketPaketi = (SoketPaketi)ar.AsyncState;
        int gelenBoyut = soketPaketi.soket.EndReceive(ar);
        if (gelenBoyut > 0)
        {
            char[] karakterler = new char[gelenBoyut + 1];
            Decoder d = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            int karakterUzunlugu = d.GetChars(soketPaketi.tampon, 0, gelenBoyut, karakterler, 0);

            String gelenVeri = new String(karakterler);
            Console.WriteLine("İstemciden Veri Geldi.. Gelen Veri : " + gelenVeri);
            Console.WriteLine("Data Recieved from client.. Received Data : " + gelenVeri);
        }
        veriBekle(soketPaketi.soket, soketPaketi.istemciNo);
    }
}
```

}

### Android Client

```
/*********************** Bağlan *********************/
/*********************** Connect *********************/

public class Baglan extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Sunucuya Bağlanılıyor..!");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        InetAddress serverAddr = null;
        try {
            serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(Evrensel.SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, Evrensel.SERVER_PORT);
            Log.d("FEF","Evrensel Socket bağlandı.." + socket.isConnected());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    socket = null;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        super.onPostExecute(v);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
/*********************** Send Message *********************/
/*********************** Mesaj Gönder *********************/
public class MesajGonder extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Sunucuya Mesaj Gönderiliyor..!");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String serverResponse = "";
        PrintWriter mBufferOut = null;
        try {
            mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            mBufferOut.println(args[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return serverResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the best way to find out which side has the problem is to run a wireshark trace.  Look for FIN or RST and tell us which side sends it first. From there you'll at least know which side is ending the session.  Do you know which side is ending the session?  Remember before any communication can happen, the two sides must notify each other. Is that even working?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem..
Problem is the Asynctask.. Do not use asynctask.. doinbackground.. Use Thread.. Runnable Thread..

### New Android Client Code is..

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static Socket socket;
    public static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.81";
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 6000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnBaglan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBaglan);
        btnBaglan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Baglan()).start();
            }
        });

        Button btnGonder = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGonder);
        btnGonder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new MesajGonder()).start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class Baglan implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InetAddress serverAddr = null;
            try {
                serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("FEF", "Socket bağlandımı:" + socket.isConnected());
        }
    }

    public class MesajGonder implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            PrintWriter mBufferOut = null;
            try {
                mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                mBufferOut.println("Breko breko");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't really a solution to your original problem, which was simply that _you closed the socket as soon as you connected it!_ The reason this new code works isn't because you switched threading models, it's because you _changed_ what the task _does_. This version of the code leaves the socket open, and so of course works better than the code that doesn't.